# Updating logged in user does not update widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a simple AuthProvider, and based on whether the `user` is null or not, show either the MainApp or Gatekeeper.

Unfortunately, even though my AuthProvider prints an updated `fbUser` value, my Widget never updates.  What am I doing wrong?

When the firebase authstate changes, I am updating the user value in AuthProvider:

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  firebaseAuth.User fbUser;

  StreamSubscription _userAuthSub;

  AuthProvider() {
    _userAuthSub = firebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((firebaseAuth.User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        fbUser = null;
      } else {
        print('User is signed in!');
        fbUser = user;
      }

      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_userAuthSub != null) {
      _userAuthSub.cancel();
      _userAuthSub = null;
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<firebaseAuth.UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final firebaseAuth.GoogleAuthCredential credential =
        firebaseAuth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return await firebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
}
```

Here's my main.dart file, where I use the AuthProvider:

```
class MeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(
            create: (_) => AuthProvider(),
          )
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(body: GatekeeperView())));
  }
}
```

And finally here is Gatekeeper consuming this AuthProvider:

```
class GatekeeperView extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _logo(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("LOGO",
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .headline2
            .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
  }

  Widget _gatekeeper(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: height,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _logo(context),
            SizedBox(height: height * 0.2),
            SizedBox(
              width: width * 0.6,
              child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        PageRouteBuilder(
                          pageBuilder: (c, a1, a2) => LoginView(),
                          transitionsBuilder: (c, anim, a2, child) =>
                              FadeTransition(opacity: anim, child: child),
                          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        ));
                  },
                  child: Text("Log In")),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (context, auth, child) {
      if (auth.fbUser != null) {
        print("OK"); // <--- this never prints even though the AuthProvider prints "User is signed in"
        return Text("Welcome you are logged in");
      }

      return _gatekeeper(context);
    }));
  }
}
```